# ms access 2007 update error run time error 3464, data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: ms-access-2007

i cannot update the data, it says that data type mismatch in criteria experession

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE PC_Details " & _
                  " SET Serial_No=" & Me.txtNo & _
                  ", PC_Brand='" & Me.txtBrand & "'" & _
                  ", PC_Model='" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
                  ", Status='" & Me.txtStatus & "'" & _
                  ", Description='" & Me.txtDesc & "'" & _
                  ", Staff_ID='" & Me.txtID & "'" & _
                  " WHERE Serial_No=" & Me.txtNo.Tag`

Comment: Since we don't have any way to tell what data types the columns you're updating are, nor what types the (presumable) textboxes actually turn out to be, this is unanswerable as written. You're just going to have to sit down and do the grunt work of working out which of those values is not what you expect. Sorry.

Comment: Please show us your table.

Answer (score 0):

Do this to debug:

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "UPDATE PC_Details " & _
                  " SET Serial_No=" & Me.txtNo & _
                  ", PC_Brand='" & Me.txtBrand & "'" & _
                  ", PC_Model='" & Me.txtModel & "'" & _
                  ", Status='" & Me.txtStatus & "'" & _
                  ", Description='" & Me.txtDesc & "'" & _
                  ", Staff_ID='" & Me.txtID & "'" & _
                  " WHERE Serial_No=" & Me.txtNo.Tag 
Debug.Print SQL
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

Then study the resulting SQL and post it here.

If all values are present, one or more is text but is handled as number or vice versa.